# Showing Post ID on RSS

Tags: rss, feed

How to showing Post ID on RSS?

This my code:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://www.ciusan.com/feed');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
//          'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<ul class="soo-latest">';
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
//      $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<li>&raquo; <a target="_blank" class="soo-info" href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a>';
        echo '<small class="help">Posted on '.$date.'</small></li>';
//      echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
```

this my permalink:

```
/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

I want using `wp_get_shortlink(get_the_ID());` for:

```
echo '<li>&raquo; <a target="_blank" class="soo-info" href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

So showing shorten not long link...

Answer (score 1):

You can add the ID as custom tag to your feed via hook. But it give no valid tag in the rss/atom standard to store this. So that I think you should split the `guid` tag to get the ID of a post, like the follow example.

The guid inside the feed:

`<guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.ciusan.com/?p=3566</guid>`

Split the ID.

`$id = explode( '=', $guid );`

The var `$guid` should you enhance in your foreach loop, so that it store each guid to each item. The `$id` get a array with all strings there a split by the string `=`, also your post id.